# Yesterday was birthday of Jon or Yesterday was THE birthday of Jon?

Tags: articles, definite-article

What is the right way to say that yesterday was a birthday to my friend?

a) Yesterday was birthday of Jon

b) Yesterday was **the** birthday of Jon?

Comment: Yesterday was the birthday of Jon. Though a native is more likely to say "yesterday was Jon's birthday"

Comment: It would be very unusual to say anything other than "Yesterday was Jon's birthday." The "of Jon" possessive construction doesn't happen often with straightforward nouns, but you could have "Yesterday was the presentation of those who were out sick yesterday".

Comment: *Jon had his birthday yesterday* is another way you'd likely hear this expressed. Or even *had a birthday yesterday*. Part of me wants to put this under Andrew's answer but I'll just leave it here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"Yesterday was Jon's birthday" is most natural.

But aside from this, as a rule, countable nouns that are *known* or *unique* require "the" or some possessive in front of them.  "Birthday" is countable, and is unique to Jon, so the practice is to use "the" in front of it.

> Yesterday was the birthday of Jon.

In a similar way, we would use "the" to describe other unique or special days which your listener should recognize (but which don't have proper names).

> Tomorrow is *the* thirty-first of October.
>
> Next Monday is *the* last day of my vacation.
>
> It was *the* first time I saw an elephant.

On the other hand, if I wanted to make it clear that this day is nothing special, or one of many similar days, I would use the indefinite article *a*:

> Tomorrow is *a* birthday of Jon.

This sounds unusual to a native speaker, again because the practice is to see each year's birthday as special.  But it would probably make sense in context.

[More info on English articles, including when they are and aren't required](http://www.davidappleyard.com/english/articles.htm)